# BigInteger switchcase

Tags: java, switch-statement, biginteger

```
   switch (n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(8)))  {
    case 1:
    case 7:
        jacobi = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        break;
    case 3:
    case 5:
       jacobi = BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
        break;}
```

I get "BigInt can't be converted to int". Switch also wants constant expressions, so I can't put BigInteger.valueOf(1), neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mod` method returns another `BigInteger`, and a `BigInteger` is a `Number`, so you can just call [`intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29) to get an `int` that can be the `switch` argument.

```
switch (n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(8)).intValue())  {
```

Comment: @BackSlash The original `n` might be really huge for all I know, but when the remainder is taken mod `8`, it'll be small.